# Ruby on Rails - cannot run the following command : rails generate rspec:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm studying Rails tutorial Chapter 3.

I cannot execute the following command. If you have an idea to solve this problem, please tell me.

Thanks.

exec command

```
bundle exec rails generate rspec:install
```

Errors

```
/Users/mofuty/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:5:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_job/railtie (LoadError)
    from /Users/mofuty/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mofuty/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `require'
    from /Users/mofuty/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.2'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.5'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.5'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

The following is apprication.rb. If you needs more details, please ask me.

config/application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want: require "active_model/railtie" require "active_job/railtie" require "active_record/railtie" require "action_controller/railtie" require "action_mailer/railtie" require "action_view/railtie" require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production. Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module SampleApp   class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true   end end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `bundle exec rails generate rspec:install`

`bundle exec` is a Bundler command to execute a script in the context of the current bundle (the one from your directory's Gemfile)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I already execute this command but the result was same;(

Comment: Ok, I see... Try to upgrade to Ruby 2.4.2

Comment: Guys, Thanks for your advice. The problem is I executed `rails new` with rails 4.2.x. So, I rebuild the project with 4.0.5. Then I could executed `bundle exec rails generate rspec:install`. I appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though your test suite is invoking some code with a dependency on the new [ActiveJob framework](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) that is part of Rails 4.

The error suggests that you do not have the railtie included in your `config/application.rb` file. If you open it, you'll likely find it is commented out, look for a line like this: `# require "active_job/railtie"`

If so, uncomment it. If that line is not included in the file, add `require "active_job/railtie"` on a new line after this `require "active_model/railtie"`.

This will ensure that the active job railtie is loaded on Rails initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advice. The problem is I executed `rails new` with rails 4.2.x. So, I rebuild the project with 4.0.5. Then I could executed `bundle exec rails generate rspec:install`. I appreciate you.